# Regex-change substring to uppercase in a string golang

Tags: regex, string, go, rune

I need to replace a string with a uppercase of the same word.So far i can search for sub-string from a text file which contains my string and replace a word like "apple" or "Apple" or "ApPle" to "APPLE". The problem exist when the string is "Is  that  pineapple  Apple  adamsApple  applepie  smell?", my search keyword exist between the other word so it cannot be found and converted.

MY final working code:

```
 //Get the txt file from the directory and search for word
  func  fileRead(getPath  string,  searchkey  string){
    var  count  int
    buf1,_:=ioutil.ReadFile(getPath);
    var  buf2=  string(buf1)
    var  b  string
    tokens:=strings.Fields(buf2)
    re := regexp.MustCompile("(?i)"+searchkey)//make searchkey case insensitive
     for  i:=0;i<len(tokens);i++{

      if  (strings.EqualFold(tokens[i],searchkey)){

      tokens[i] = re.ReplaceAllString(tokens[i], strings.ToUpper(searchkey))
      count++

     }else{

      tokens[i]=re.ReplaceAllLiteralString(tokens[i],strings.ToUpper(searchkey))
      count++
         }
        }
        for  j:=0;  j<len(tokens);  j++{
         b+=  tokens[j]
         b+="  "  
          }
        c  :=  []byte(b)
        fmt.Println(count,"                  ",getPath)
        ioutil.WriteFile(getPath,  c,  0644)//rights back to the file
   }
```

Comment: Please use gofmt or use an editor or ide that does it for you :(

Comment: I took the liberty to format the code in your question for you. Please try to submit well-indented and readable code next time; poorly indented code is a pain for everybody else to read and significantly worses the propability to receive an answer.

Comment: use regex `\bapple\b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use regexp for that, a simple [example](http://play.golang.org/p/MgLFPZB0XW):

```
func KeywordsToUpper(src string, keywords ...string) string {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`\b(` + strings.Join(keywords, "|") + `)\b`)
    return re.ReplaceAllStringFunc(src, func(w string) string {
        return strings.ToUpper(w)
    })
}
```

//edit

I think I misunderstood the question, if all you want is to replace a word even if it's in the middle of other words, like `myapplecomputer` then using `strings.Replace` should be enough, for example:

```
func ReplaceLikeYouDontCare(src string, words ...string) string {
    for _, w := range words {
        src = strings.Replace(src, w, strings.ToUpper(w), -1)
    }
    return src
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to use both regex and replace. The solution requires to have searchkey to be in any case and the string to be edited can also have any case. eg. searchkey:"Apple" string:"BigApples"or"ApPlEs" etc.

Comment: `regexp.MustCompile(`\b(?i:` + strings.Join(keywords, "|") + `)\b`)` makes it case insensitive. Notice the `?i:` part.

Comment: sorry, I am getting this error: cannot use keywords (type string) as type []string in argument to strings.Join. I am trying use s=[]string(keyword) but it is unable to change.

Comment: in my example it can support multiple keywords, if you just want one simply replace `strings.Join(keywords, "|")` with `keywords`.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't [strings.Replace](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replace) exactly what you're looking for?

```
func fileRead(getPath string, searchkey string) {
    buf, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(getPath)
    strings.Replace(string(buf), searchkey, strings.ToUpper(searchkey), -1)
}
```